# Why does this popup window only show as a small square?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm making a simple app, where you click a button, and it displays a popup with a random string from the button.

The problem is, when the pop up window is created, its a small box. like 100x100 or something. Here is the popup code. You can see I tried setting 550, and 750, as the size, if I put 70, and 550, it will work perfectly and be really small width, and stretched long wise. But after like 100dp, it goes back to square

```
  public void showPopup(View v){

        View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 550, 750);

        // Example: If you have a TextView inside `popup_layout.xml`
        TextView tv = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        String[] myString;
        Resources res = getResources();
        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);

        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        tv.setText(q);



        // Initialize more widgets from `popup_layout.xml`


        // If the PopupWindow should be focusable
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

        // If you need the PopupWindow to dismiss when when touched outside
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());



        // Get the View's(the one that was clicked in the Fragment) location
       //v.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        // Using location, the PopupWindow will be displayed right under anchorView
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
```

Here is my popup layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blank">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Try `match_parent` instead